# Ant task to pick a file during runtime?

Tags: ant

I need to pick a file using Ant during runtime, right now I managed to do this with exec and zenity like this:

```
<exec executable="zenity" outputproperty="file">
  <arg line="--file-selection" />
  <arg line='--title "Pick a file to upload"' />
</exec>
<echo message="Uploading ${file} ..."/>
```

I wish to know if there is a task to do this, since this one is platform dependant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a jar file to do the dirty job, here is what I did:

1- downloaded and compiled this FileChooser example: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/core/files/javafilechooser.html, only changing f.getName() to f.getAbsolutePath()

2- added a java task:

```
<java jar="FileChooser.jar" outputproperty="filepath" fork="true"/>
```

now I just need to carry FileChooser.jar along in other platforms, it is not perfect but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't use user input when you run Ant. You can select a file when you start Ant by using a property:

```
 $ ant -Dfile=my_file

 <project>
     <echo>You're using file "${file}"</echo>
 </project>
```

However, you can use the [<input>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html) task for this:

```
<project>
    <input addproperty="file"
    defaultvalue="foo.txt"
    message="What file do you want?"/>
    <echo>You've chosen file "${file}"</echo>
</project>

 $ ant
 What file do you want? [foo.txt]
 my.file.txt
 You've chosen file "my.file.txt"
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Thanks David, but I don't want to type the whole path, I want something like the example that I have posted above but not constrained to linux, maybe some built-in java file chooser dialog if there is no ant task for that ...

Comment: Then you can write an Ant task that pops a file chooser dialog and then set a property in the ant `project`. Well, that's not Ant's way.

Comment: Hi coolcfan, this is what I am doing, I know it is not Ant's way but it is what I need right now ...

Answer (score -2):

AntForm provides a fileSelectionProperty form which may be helpful here as well.  This is an example of how to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
getFile
    - get file name with a file selection box
-->
<project name="files" default="-getFile" basedir="."
            xmlns:antform="antlib:com.sardak.antform">

    <!--
    antform
    http://antforms.sourceforge.net/
    provides pop-up forms and menus for user input
        <antform>
        <antmenu>
    -->
    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.sardak.antform"
            resource="com/sardak/antform/taskdefs.properties"
            classpath="../../lib/antform.jar"/>

    <target name="-getFile">

        <!--
        pop-up form
        user selection form for the file selection
        -->
        <antform:antform title="Please Select a File">
            <fileSelectionProperty label="File: "
                    property="file.selection"
                    directoryChooser="false"/>
            <controlbar>
                <button label="OK" type="ok"/>
                <button label="QUIT" target="Quit"/>
            </controlbar>
        </antform:antform>
        <echo message="You chose file ${file.selection}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```